# W3C validation errors need to solve

Tags: javascript, html, css, w3c, w3c-validation

I have some error in W3C validation

I set `<!DOCTYPE HTML>` for my page but i have some error and as per below image

[image]

I am try to solve this but not getting success.

Please give me suggestion for all 3 error.
By which way i can solve this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Line 10:  this is for the SSL verification - when you have done this, you can remove this meta tag.

Lines 15 & 16:  These are to set the default mime types for Javascript and CSS. They are both unnecessary, as those are the defaults, and can be safely removed.

Comment: are you sure if i removed it than it will not effect to my site content or functionality? I just conform because this is my live site and lots of customer visit site now

Answer (score 1):

Line 15 and Line 16 are content types that should be used in  and  tags.

As for the error on line 10, no idea.

Comment: so for solve error on line number 15 and 16 what i need to do? can you suggest me? @Richard A

Comment: You can just remove them, no problem.